# I can't find a method to save the values in a hash directly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, hash

I'm a newbie to rails, and I have researched a whole day. I think my problem is easy.

There is a table **questions_tags_relation**, it has two columns(no id):

```
columns:
question_id -> string
tag_id -> string
```

And I have a **hash**:

```
record = {:question_id=>'111111', :tag_id=>'22222'}
```

And there is **no model 'QuestionsTags'**, and I don't want to create one.

Now I can get the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`, but how to insert the hash to table using simple code? I hope these is a `save` method:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.save 'questions_tags', record
```

Is there such a method?

---

**UPDATE**

I'm asking this question because I met some problems when I saved data to the database by using ActiveRecord models. Maybe using `connection` directly will be simpler. Some of the tables are `join` tables, they don't have a primary key, that's why there is no `id` in my example. I hope there is a simple way to save a hash to a table, but I can't find it. Thanks, friends

Comment: it is bad db design to not use some kind of unique index. Is there any reason why you don't have an id column?

Comment: Programmers have the tendency to give advice when they see something wrong (even those they perceive to be wrong). I do not know the answer, but your update sounds not so right to me.

Comment: @Vijay, thank you. I'm fixing it now

Comment: appreciate taking time to change the update text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a junction table for a many-to-many relationship, you shouldn't have an id field.  In fact, rails will fail loudly if you try to do that since it confuses things.

Typically, if you don't want the join model to be created, just use [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.2.2/doc/index.html?a=M001530&name=has_and_belongs_to_many#) which doesn't require it.  Then you can say `@question.tags` which will do the joining through the appropriate table.  You should use the appropriate table name (or override it with :join_table).

Once you've created the association, you can use it like so:

```
@question.tags << Tag.first
@question.tags.each { |t| t.name }
# ... and so on
```

Edit:
I know this doesn't answer the question of how to connect to the database, but I hope I'm answering the question-behind-the-question of how to access a many-to-many relationship without creating a join model for the intermediary table.

Comment: thanks so much, you taught me know the word 'junction table', I was wondering what's the name of these kind of tables in English. And your answer is helpful, thank you:)

Comment: Great!  Does it answer your question or is there something you still need?

Comment: I have read some ActiveRecord source code, and found rails has not 'prepared statement' like Java, I think that's way there is no method to insert a hash to a table, because it's complicated, and not very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an ID then your best bet is going to be to address your DB directly. Otherwise just add an id feild and create a Model, its the sensible thing to do unless you have a *serious* reason not to.